# Why am I getting an "access is denied" error after running bitdefender on a file?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, bitdefender

I had a file "Patch.exe" that originally worked fine. I could move it to folders without an issue.

But then I scanned it with Bitdefender and it came up as malware (it is not) and I deleted the file because at the time I didn't realize it was a false positive.

Anyway, when I try to download the Patch.exe file again, I get an "access denied" error.

```
C:\Users\pitca\OneDrive\Documents\workstation\Shared Files\DigiDNA iMazing 2.11.7 incl Patch [CrackingPatching]\Patch.zip: Cannot create C:\Users\pitca\OneDrive\Documents\workstation\Shared Files\DigiDNA iMazing 2.11.7 incl Patch [CrackingPatching]\Patch\Patch.exe   Access is denied.
```

I'm the administrator so I should still have access to this file. How do I fix this? I can't even reset permissions since I'm not even able to download the file again now.

Comment: Does [How to add Antivirus exceptions](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/13427/) answer your question?

Comment: No -- I'm getting this error even after adding these files to the exceptions list.